# Airy function's identity.

Tags: special-functions, airy-functions

Suppose that $z>0$ and let us write $z=v^2$ where $v>0$, the question is how to show that from $Ai(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \cos(\frac{1}{3}t^3+zt)dt$ that: 
$$Ai(v^2)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_I \exp(v^2 s-1/3 s^3)ds$$
where $I$ is the imaginary axis from $-\infty i$ to $+\infty i$.

I first tried the identity: $\cos(\ldots)= \frac{1}{2} (\exp(i\ldots)+\exp(-i\ldots))$, but I don't see how to continue from there?

Thanks!

Comment: $\cos$ is an even function, while $\sin$ is odd, which means you can transform: $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \cos(\frac{1}{3}t^3+zt)dt= \\ = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \cos(\frac{1}{3}t^3+zt)+i \sin (\frac{1}{3}t^3+zt)  \right)dt$$

Comment: @YuriyS That's literally the answer.

Comment: @PeterForeman, I don't like posting short answers, so anybody is welcome to post their own ;)

Comment: @YuriyS yes it was trivial, as all of maths when done right. :-) cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
Ai(v^2)&=\frac1\pi\int_0^\infty \cos\left(\frac13t^3+v^2t\right)\,dt\\&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_\mathbb R\cos\left(\frac13t^3+v^2t\right)\,dt\\&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_\mathbb R\cos\left(\frac13t^3+v^2t\right)+i \sin\left(\frac13t^3+v^2t\right)\,dt\\&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\mathbb R e^{i (\frac13t^3+v^2t)}\,d(it)\\&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_Ie^{v^2s-\frac13s^3}\,ds.
\end{align*}